# Creating a page only to be accessed by registered users

Tags: 7, users

at my site [tobynews](http://www.tobynews.com) I have users that would be registered as an "author." What I'd like to do is create a page such as an "Author's Resources" page that would only be accessible by someone who is registered as an author through the site. I'm not exactly sure how to approach this, other than trying to connect to the database's user table with a form. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that using Drupal's [role based access control system](https://drupal.org/node/120614).

For example, assign the role of "author" to the author users.
You can then restrict access to the "Author Resources" page by user role.
e.g

1. Create a page using the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module and adding an access restriction.
2. Create a page using [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and restrict access to that role in the "access callback"

Answer (score 0):

Or (following on from David Thomas' answer) if you are using Panels you can restrict access by roles.